# get echarts on click event to change value of variable attached to $scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, echarts

I am using echarts in my angularjs project. I would prefer not to have to use the ng-echarts module if possible. I would like to be able to get a click event on the chart object to change the value of a variable on the $scope that can be used to toggle ng-show

My code in the controller is like this:

```
myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

// code that prepares the graph data goes here
// ...

myChart.setOption(option,true); 

myChart.on('click', function(e) {

  //this works fine
  console.log(e) 

  // this does nothing
  $scope.showDiv = true //this does nothing
})
```

Is there a way of getting the `$scope.showDiv = true` to actually work on a `<div ng-if="showDiv">test</div>` in the view?

I have searched the documentation and other sources but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you aren't using angular's `ng-click` function, which automatically wraps the code in an `$apply()`. Since you are using non-angular code you need to do this yourself. Just add `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your method. [This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) has some good information about this.

> **When Do You Call $apply() Manually?**
>
> If AngularJS usually wraps our code in $apply() and starts a $digest cycle, then when do you need to do call $apply() manually? Actually, AngularJS makes one thing pretty clear. It will account for only those model changes which are done inside AngularJS’ context (i.e. the code that changes models is wrapped inside $apply()). Angular’s built-in directives already do this so that any model changes you make are reflected in the view. However, if you change any model outside of the Angular context, then you need to inform Angular of the changes by calling $apply() manually. It’s like telling Angular that you are changing some models and it should fire the watchers so that your changes propagate properly.

---

On a side note, I would recommend using the `ng-echarts` as well as `ng-click` instead of `on('click',..)`. Using angular directives and frameworks makes the code much easier to follow, implement, and debug.

Comment: Figured it out before I saw this! But right answer nonetheless! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple `$scope.$apply()` did the trick. duh.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I thought `ng-echarts` was a total mess, with 100+ lines of code, so I wrote my own for angular 1.5+.

It's only 20 lines, and does everything you need, including (animated) updating the chart when your `config` or `option` variables changes (automatically detected through `$onChanges`).

May help you or others in the future.

---

**Component**

```
app.component('chart', {
    bindings: {
        config      : '<',
        option      : '<'
    },
    controller: function ($element, $window) {
        let chart = echarts.init($element[0]);

        this.$onInit = function() {
            angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {
                chart.resize()
            });
        }

        this.$onChanges = function(changes) {
            chart.setOption(this.option, this.refresh);
            chart.resize();
            chart.hideLoading();
        }
    }
})
```

**Template**

```
<chart
    option="myChart.option" 
    config="myChart.config">
</chart>
```

**CSS**

```
// Fix for Bootstrap init width
chart {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 250px; 
    float: left;
}
```